# Python to Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I upload my data to firebase using python, but instead of autogenerating the path for my data in realtime database. How can I make it myself?
Example:

[image]

I do not want the MGRhisI5hSiYUs9fr0s but I want my own word.
This are my code:

```
db = firebase.database()
data_to_upload = {
    "result": result
}
db.child("testResult").push(data_to_upload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the path, don't use `push()`, which generates a random ID. Build a path to the location to update, and use `set()`, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-ways-to-save).

```
db.child("choose").child("your").child("path").set(data_to_upload)
```